# How to use between clause in select statement in codeigneiter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from database by taking one data row from one table and use those values as where condition. and then i tried pass json string to controller class. but i'm unable to reach this. how should i write this code
This is code i used to get data.

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM todaywork WHERE idEmployee = $user ");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           $row = $query->row(); 

               $from = $row->T_frange;
               $to = $row->T_trange;
               $note = $row->T_note;
        }     
               $this->db->select("cus.idCustomer,cus.C_name,f.F_itemname,ctr.*");
                //$whereCondition = array('cus.idCustomer' => $_POST['custId']);
                $this->db->where('C_trnoofarr BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}');
                //filter where
                $this->db->from('customer cus');
                $this->db->join('contracts AS ctr', 'cus.idCustomer = ctr.idCustomer', 'INNER');
                $this->db->join('facility AS f','ctr.idContracts = f.idContracts','INNER');
                $query = $this->db->get();

                return $query->result();

    }
```

Comment: `$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}',NULL,FALSE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for between

```
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr >', $from);
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr <', $to);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be 1st `greater than` and 2nd `less than`

Comment: @ParagTyagi yup will change it

Answer (score 1):

Replace this,

```
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}');
```

with this,

```
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr >', $from);
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr <', $to);
```

---

Still if you want to use raw in `WHERE` clause you've to add a third parameter as well.

```
$this->db->where('<where clause>', NULL, FALSE);
```

**From [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):**

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

In your case maybe like this,

```
$this->db->where('C_trnoofarr BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}', NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                $this->db->select('*'); 
                $this->db->from('company');
                $this->db->where("grade BETWEEN $first AND $second");
                $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: Can you explain **what** you've changed and why? Is there any chance that your query is now open to SQL injections? What would happen if `$first` contains `1 AND 10`?